# Isolate between NT user account or local user profile issue

Tags: windows-7, windows, troubleshooting

I have confusion/query related with error isolation.

My question is how do I determine/isolate or distinguish whether issue is related to NT user account or local user profile on the same machine? Is there any simple isolation technique to get answer of above query?

Comment: Get your user to log in on a different machine, if the issues occur on that machine the problem is with the roaming account.

Comment: Let me rephrase the exact situation. Support other user login to the machine and issue does not appear. It means there could be issues either in original user NT account or original user profile on that specific machine. Now My question is how do I figure out whether it's user profile or user account on that machine?

Comment: If original user login to different machine, there will be new profile and new user account on the different machine. So login to different machine does not isolate between original user profile and original user account.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and put that clarification into it. Please see [ask] and take our [tour] for tips on improving your question.